# Performance for multiple searches ordered by random

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm in the design phase of a website and I have a solution for a feature but I don't know if it will be the good one when the site, hopefully, grows. I want the users to be able to perform searches for other users and the results they find must be ordered: first the "spotlighted" users, then all the rest. The result must be ordered randomly, respecting the previously mentioned order, and with pagination.

One of the solutions I have in mind is to store the query results in a session variable in the server side. For performance, when the user leaves the search this variable is destroyed.

What will happen when the site has thousands of users and every day thousands of searches are performed? My solution will be viable or the server will be overloaded?

I have more solutions in mind like an intermediate table where n times by day users are dumped in the mentioned order. This way there is no need to create a big array in the user's session and pagination is done via multiple queries against the database.

Although I appreciate any suggestions I'm specially interested into hear opinions from developers seasoned in transited sites.

(The technology employed is LAMP, with InnoDb tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Premature optimization is bad. But you should be planning ahead.** You dont need to implement it. But prepare yourself.

If there are thousands of users searching this query everyday then caching the query result in session is not a good idea. Cause same result can be cached for some users while other needs to execute it.  For such case I'd recommend you save the search result in user independent data structure (File, memory etc).

1. For each search query save the result, creation date, last access date in your disk or in memory.
2. If any user searches the same query show the result from cache
3. Run a cron that invalidates the cache after sometime.

This way frequent searches will most time promptly available. Also it reduces the load on your database.

Comment: You are mentioning the point I worry about: memory (ab)use. Trying to avoid database overload using session variables may derive into bigger performance issues? I'm absolutely ignorant about how PHP deals with the session data. Seems it stores the data in files located in "session.save-path" (usually /var/tmp) I don't want to be in this future situation: "hey, maybe my website is slow as hell but look, there isn't any bottleneck in the database!"

Comment: @Bambam I didn't specify where to store your cache. You can store it anywhere. Memory is best location. Use memcache for this. I have already specified the problem with session. Its per user basis.

Comment: Therefore, your answer for the question "Trying to avoid database overload using session variables may derive into bigger performance issues?" is "no, just the opposite"?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the answer you are looking for, but I have to say it.
[Premature Optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Get that site up with a simple implementation of that query and come back and ask if that turns out to be your worst bottleneck.

Comment: I have read this sentence before. This is not wasting a lot of time in an almost insignificant performance gain. Users will search a lot. In this case, to think "first better to wait until users really begin to search a lot" is like to think "first wait until your site is minimally successful and only then begin to worry how it works". I'm developing for success, not for failure, although I'm fully aware that failure is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to decrease the hitting on the DB by caching search results so other users searching for the same set of factors don't have to hit the DB again--especially on very loose query strings on non-indexed fields.  If so, you can't store it in a session--that's only available to the single user.

I'd use a caching layer like Cache_Lite and cache the result set from the db query based on the query string (not the sql query, but the search parameters from your site).  That way identical searches will be cached.  Handle the sorting and pagination of the array in PHP, not in the DB.